# PHP can not require the the file that contains `_()`

Tags: php

Sorry for this, recently our country can not access google, so I can not query messages in the network, and I also rookie for PHP.

I have a `error.inc.php`:

```
<?php

...
define("SUC_EXEC_PDNSSEC_REMOVE_ZONE_KEY", _('Zone key has been deleted successfully.'));
define("SUC_EXEC_PDNSSEC_ACTIVATE_ZONE_KEY", _('Zone key has been successfully activated.'));
define("SUC_EXEC_PDNSSEC_DEACTIVATE_ZONE_KEY", _('Zone key has been successfully deactivated.'));

function error($msg) {
    echo "     <div class=\"error\">Error: " . $msg . "</div>\n";
}

?>
```

In my `index.php`:

```
<?php

echo "before include";
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/poweradmin/inc/error.inc.php");
echo "included error.inc.php";  # there do not print to the screen when I access the index.php
...
```

You see the notation, when I access the index.php, I can not print this line code(`echo "included error.inc.php";`) in my browser screen, means there is something wrong with `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/poweradmin/inc/error.inc.php");` this line.

I don't know why I can not require_once the `error.inc.php`, I don't know whether is caused by the `_()`, and I don't know what the `_()` stands for.

---

**EDIT**

And the question main purpose is why the `error.inc.php` can not be require_once into the index.php, who can tell me this?

Comment: [`_()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php#refsect1-function.gettext-notes) is an alias of function [`gettext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php#refsect1-function.gettext-notes).

Comment: Turn on error reporting  . error_reporting(E_ALL); Place this at the top of the script. You should see what's going on

Comment: @Akintunde Where to turn on it?

Comment: Several functions must be invoked before using [`_()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) (aka [`gettext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)), to prepare its working environment. See the example in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know why I can not require_once the error.inc.php, I don't
>   know whether is caused by the _(), and I don't know what the _()
>   stands for.

`_()` OR `gettext()` functions are same

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php